# How to truncate y-axis not from zero in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggbreak

In R, I tried the following code for bar chart.
I want to truncate y-axis and make it start not from zero, I tried 'coord_cartesian', but it failed. I was wondering if there is better way to do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  value = c(2, 20, 18)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x=category, y=value, fill=category)) + 
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Type", y="Value")+
  scale_y_break(c(3,15),
                scales=1,
                space=1,
                expand = c(0,0))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 20))
```

[image]

Comment: I know this isn't helpful to answering your question, but thought I'd share it anyways in case this changes your mind on whether you actually want to start your bar graph at a non-zero number: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184525/how-to-determine-whether-or-not-the-y-axis-of-a-graph-should-start-at-zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a very bad plot. A barplot starts always at 0. But you can do this with `geom_linerange`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=category, ymin = 1, ymax = value, color=category)) + 
  geom_linerange(linewidth = 60) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Type", y="Value")+
  scale_y_break(c(3,15),
                scales=1,
                space=1,
                expand = c(0,0)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes =list(linewidth = 6)))
```

[image: resulting plot]